# MobileFirst Operational Analytics v7.1 startup error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I am facing a problem when accessing MobileFirst Operational Analytics console. 
I've changed the classloader order as specified by this [link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_installing_op_analytics_websphere.html); 
I did not do any changes for master node and shards configuration, I just leave it as default. 
This error happens after starting the application and on the browser is shown just loading image. 
**My MobileFirst enviroment is:** 
IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation v7.1 (fix: IF201509071904); 
IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment v8.5.5.6 
Linux Redhat 6.6 (vSphere)

```
 [16/09/15 21:50:37:580 BRT] 000000a2 IndexManager  E   MSAN217E: Error creating Elasticsearch mappings 
                java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.sdk.Utilities.loadEventTypesMappingFiles(Utilities.java:115)
    at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.node.elasticsearch.IndexManager.addMappings(IndexManager.java:168)
    at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.node.elasticsearch.IndexManager.initializeIndex(IndexManager.java:143)
    at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.node.elasticsearch.NodeManager.initializeDefaultNode(NodeManager.java:100)
    at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.node.elasticsearch.NodeManager.getClient(NodeManager.java:134)
    at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.rest.elasticsearch.ESUtility.getDefaultTenant(ESUtility.java:681)
    at com.ibm.mobile.analytics.server.rest.IndexManagerResource.getIndices(IndexManagerResource.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
```

Could anyone please help me on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Does the path to your WAS installation contain any spaces?  If so, try removing all spaces from the absolute path to your WAS installation.

Comment: Hi Zac, my paths are: WAS_HOME=/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer; MFP_HOME=/usr/IBM/MobileFirst; As you can see w/ any space. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From initial code analysis by the MobileFirst development team this may be due to a regression.

As there is no local workaround, the suggestion is to open a PMR (customer support ticket) with a link to this question, to have it further investigated and provide a code fix if deemed needed.

Comment: Hi Idan, Do we have any update on this issue. I tried to setup MFPF 7.1 analytics, getting the same issue.

Comment: The latest fix pack available is interim fix: 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201509132345, But it not loading in Installation Manager. Unable to find any update. Any idea were it goes wrong.

Comment: The latest in IBM Fix Central should be from October 5th. This is where the fix will be.

Comment: I wonder why its not listing in my Passport Advantage portal. The only iFix is see is Sep 13 and older one Sep 07.

Comment: I'll get back to you about that. Note that you can always open a PMR if it is important enough for you and request an iFix containing the fix.